# Is it possible to get the declared name of variable within a method? Groovy

Tags: groovy

I was wondering if it's posible to get the declared name of a variable within a method? So I can print it out or do something with the name later on. Hopefully the below code example gives more meaning.

Code example:

```
class Foo {

   public method(String param) {
       println param.(the method I don't know) +": "+ param
   }
}


Foo foo = new Foo()
String myStringVar = "This is a string for testing"
foo.method(myStringVar) //Should print out: "myStringVar: This is a string for testing"
```

Comment: This is not possible... you don't pass the variable (with information about the variable), you pass a reference to the value of the variable

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Perhaps what you want to do might be better accomplished in another manner.

Comment: mostly curiosity... but the idea was to build up a binding strategy from domain to a form class with automatic binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible out of the box. But you can use named arguments:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_named_arguments